# AVPlayer Audio Muted

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I am new to Xcode,please help me out. I added AVPlayer in View Controller in IOS app.It displays Video in view But without audio. Any help anybody
Advance thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason you audio is mute because you might have not initialize AVAudioSession Check this out ..

```
 AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];


UIView *myView = previewView;

videoController  = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoPlayUrl];
videoController.view.frame = myView.bounds;

[videoController.view setBounds:previewView.bounds];
videoController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
videoController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
videoController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
videoController.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
[previewView.layer addSublayer:videoController.view.layer];

[videoController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```